# Какой знак препинания следует поставить?

Tags: пунктуация

Сторонниками секуляризации облика храма являются *N* и *M* **(?)** авторы руководств по проектированию *X* церквей.

Answer (score 3):

В данном случае перед приложением лучше поставить тире, так как приложение распространённое, носит пояснительный характер и находится в конце предложения.

*Сторонниками секуляризации облика храма являются N и M – авторы руководств по проектированию церквей.*

...2. Наряду с запятыми, распространенные приложения могут выделяться тире:

а) если приложение имеет значение уточнения или пояснения.

Например: *Рязанцев и Зоя – его жена – были из одного класса  (Зал.); И теперь двое дядей по отцу и Иван Маркович – дядя матери – решают задачу*  (Ч.);

б) если приложение достаточно распространено.
Например: *Беллетрист Бескудников – тихий, прилично одетый человек с внимательными и в то же время неуловимыми глазами – вынул часы (Булг.);*

в) если приложение стоит в конце предложения.
Например: *Наконец появился и механик – молодой парень, еще не снявший институтского значка (Расп.); Пахнет дождем – нежным и вместе с тем острым запахом влаги, сырых садовых дорожек (Пауст.); Какая она была твердая и ласковая – эта невысокая, довольно полная женщина (Зал.).*

Такие приложения обладают большой самостоятельностью, часто содержат в себе развернутую характеристику предмета или лица. [Обособленные определения и приложения](http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/262-obosoblennyeopredeleniyaiprilogeniya.html?start=1******)

Answer (score 0):

Вторая часть (авторы ...) является приложением и может отделяться запятой или тире (тире ставится, если нужно подчеркнуть оттенок самостоятельности этого приложения). Чисто интуитивно я бы предпочел здесь запятую. Кроме того, если было Х руководств и Х церквей, то лучше сказать "..авторы Х руководств по проектированию церквей"

**Сторонниками секуляризации облика храма являются N и M, авторы Х руководств по проектированию церквей.**

Comment: Х церквей... Икс, предполагаю,здесь подразумевает не количество, а определение типа нового сооружения (конструктивного, скорее всего) или восстанавливаемого.